# Making an L-curve with sklearn's ridge regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics, linear-regression

A common way to visualize the solution of [ridge regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RidgeCV.html) is an [L curve](https://www.sintef.no/globalassets/project/evitameeting/2005/lcurve.pdf) which plots the sum of squared errors against the ridge penalty for different choices of the regularization parameter. Is this possible to make with sklearn?

Comment: Sklearn and Python provide all the necessary building blocks but there is no off-the-shelf implementation I am aware of.

Comment: @kazemakase indeed there is with [Yellowbrick](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/index.html) - see answer below; although it's funny that such functionality which exists for years off the self in the respective R packages has found its way to Python only recently with *external* packages...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a pure sklearn answer:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge

alphas = np.logspace(-10, 10, 1000)
solution_norm = []
residual_norm = []

for alpha in alphas: 
    lm = Ridge(alpha=alpha)
    lm.fit(X, y)
    solution_norm += [(lm.coef_**2).sum()]
    residual_norm += [((lm.predict(X) - y)**2).sum()]

plt.loglog(residual_norm, solution_norm, 'k-')
plt.show()
```

where `X` and `y` are your predictors and targets, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such built-in functionality in scikit-learn, but such functionality is provided by the [Yellowbrick](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/index.html) library (install with `pip` or [`conda`](https://anaconda.org/DistrictDataLabs/yellowbrick)); adapting the LassoCV example from their [documentation](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/regressor/alphas.html) to your RidgeCV case gives:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeCV
from yellowbrick.regressor import AlphaSelection
from yellowbrick.datasets import load_concrete

# Load the regression dataset
X, y = load_concrete()

# Create a list of alphas to cross-validate against
alphas = np.logspace(-10, 1, 40)

# Instantiate the linear model and visualizer
model = RidgeCV(alphas=alphas)
visualizer = AlphaSelection(model)
visualizer.fit(X, y)
visualizer.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Note though that this is not actually the l curve. The l curve shows on the y-axis the ridge penalty (i.e., the sum of square coefficients, not the ridge parameter) and on the x-axis the error (i.e., the sum of square residuals).